# xlwings saves workbook as web page, need to save as 97-2003 workbook (.xls)

Tags: python-3.x, excel-2013, xlwings

xlwings' workbook.save method is saving excel files as webpages, I need to save them in .xls format.

I am pulling the excel files from a website and I believe that's why they are defaulting to save as a webpage. I've tried using:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Workbook("Full path name\\template.xls")
'''some formatting code'''
wb.save("New path name\\formatted_template.xls")
```

I've also tried saving to the default directory:

```
wb.save("formatted_template.xls")
```

In both cases it returns .xls files saved as webpages. The only way I can save them in .xls format (not as webpages) would be to keep all files open and manually save as .xls for each one, but this would be much more time consuming than if I could automate the process.

I apologize if I've missed any posting etiquette as this is my first post.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, currently the option to save a workbook as a certain type is not natively supported yet. Use this workaround instead for now (Windows version):

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import FileFormat
wb.api.SaveAs(your_path, FileFormat.xlExcel8)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I did however have to use xw.FileFormat.xlExcel8 to get the SaveAs method to work for me (I'm using Excel 2013 on Windows 7).

Comment: Can this answer be updated to cover more recent versions of xlwings?

Comment: Thank you. I think another change is that `xw.FileFormat` has moved to `xw.constants.FileFormat`.